# from Calendar to ChronoLocalDateTime

Tags: java, date, time, java-time, localdate

I want to know if a `LocalDateTime` is after yesterday, so I make this comparison, but I don't know how to pass from Calendar to `ChronoLocalDateTime`

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
lastClientEvent.getDateReceived().isAfter(cal);
```

Comment: When you can use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, there is no reason also to use the outdated classes like `Calendar`. `java.time` offers all the functionality you need (as demonstrated in [the answer by YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886244/5772882), for example).

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the legacy date-time classes are entirely supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Your Question is flawed in its attempt to mix the legacy with the modern. No need for you to ever touch `Calendar` or `Date` classes again. To interface with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, call new conversion methods on the old legacy class to convert back-and-forth. But write all your new code in *java.time* only.

Comment: Another thing, you should not be using `LocalDateTime` if you are tracking actual moments. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it *cannot* represent a moment. It represents *potential* moment along a range of about 26-27 hours (the range of time zones). For actual moments you should be using `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`.  `Instant.now()` captures the current moment in UTC. `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId )` captures the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by yesterday exactly, if you mean yesterday any date before today midnight you can use :

```
LocalDateTime yesterday = LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")),
        LocalTime.MIDNIGHT
); 
=> 2018-06-16T00:00
```

If you mean yesterday the midnight of yesterday you can use `minusDays(1)` :

```
LocalDateTime yesterday = LocalDateTime.of(
        LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")),
        LocalTime.MIDNIGHT
).minusDays(1);
=> 2018-06-15T00:00
```

Then you can compare your dates with this :

```
LocalDateTime anyDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.JUNE, 16, 9, 27, 50);
if (anyDate.isAfter(yesterday)) { }
```

---

Another solution by [@Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886224/from-calendar-to-chronolocaldatetime/50886244?noredirect=1#comment88774632_50886244) you can use :

```
LocalDateTime anyDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.JUNE, 16, 9, 27, 50);
LocalDate zoneDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"));
if (anyDate.toLocalDate().isAfter(zoneDate)) { }
```

Comment: Nice and correct answer. Unless the cut time is “24 hours ago”, I might use `anyDate.toLocalDate()` to get a `LocalDate` and then compare it to for example `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"))` (today in Spain).

Comment: thank you @OleV.V. this is nice to detect that the OP is from Spain from the OP's name :) I edit my answer hope this is what you mean

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was thinking of (Google Translate thanks that the text in the asker’s profile page is in Catalan, so I figured, though of course en Peris may live anywhere on Earth).

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it like this:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
Date ts = cal.getTime();
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(ts.getTime());
LocalDateTime yesterday = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());

if(lastClientEvent.getDateReceived().isAfter(yesterday){..}
```

Comment: Not a good Answer. (A) Ignores crucial issue of time zone. (B) Needlessly uses terribly troublesome legacy date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque The other answer reported the way to do it using the new Java date API. This answer was jusg supposed to complete OP's code.

Comment: Very well. My comment is a warning to the reader that these classes are now obsolete. No down-vote from me. And I am pointing out the flaw in the Question – these legacy classes should not have been used at all if the author has access to the *java.time* framework. Never mix the legacy and modern classes, it is senseless.